Visual Studio Code is being really weird about python interpreters
I am trying to use the neat-python package. I had to install it directly from the github using pip install git+https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python.git because they haven't updated their pypi in a while. While writing this I made it work from the global interpreter, but the venv that I want to use reliably (see also in the global interpreter picture) does not work in the debugger, only in the terminal.
I now have a script that reads import neat;print("completed"). When I run it in the terminal, it runs just fine, but when I press F5 for the debugger and run it there it just fails to find the module.
After some further work I think I have realised that the interpreter found by VSCode is just an entirely different one, even after I manually activate the venv. I think I'm losing all understanding of what is going on. I managed to load that one up with all the modules I need, so I can use it as a substitute for debugging, wherever it is.
I have tried looking it up, but I don't think I understand VScode well enough to ask the right questions

Have you selected the correct python interpreter via the command pallet?

In your case you probably activated a venv by accident. You will need to use command which python to check which python interpreter/environment. Then installing the necessary package with pip will work.
